# Is it possible to speedup scipy's periodogram function with numba's jit?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, numba

I need to speedup a program, and my bottleneck is
the computation of the periodogram, (I use the one implemented by scipy).  I tried to speed it up using numba.

The first question is: does it make sense to try to compile the function periodogram with jit?   Is it not already optimized?

If the answer is no, then I have a compilation problem. This is a minimal version:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import periodogram
from numba import jit
a=np.random.randn(10000)
per_j = jit("f8[5](f8[10000],f8,f8[8],i4, b1,b1,b1,i4)",nopython=True)(periodogram)
res=per_j(a,fs=1.0,window=np.hamming(8),nfft=8,detrend=False,return_onesided=True,scaling='density', axis=-1)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "periodjit.py", line 5, in <module>
    per_j = jit("f8[5](f8[10000],f8,f8[8],i4, b1,b1,b1,i4)",nopython=True)(periodogram)
  :
(I removed intermediate messages) 
 :
TypingError: Untyped global name 'welch'
File "../../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 140

Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'welch'
File "../../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 140
```

I think it makes no sense to try to modify spectral.py, thus my first question.

Finally, is there a faster implmentation available?

My software is:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
:
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.17.1'
>>> numba.__version__
'0.26.0'
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.11.1'
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the `periodogram` function?  It doesn't make much sense to just throw `numba` at a function, without knowing what that function is doing, and especially what it is calling.

The code is:

```
x = np.asarray(x)

if x.size == 0:
    return np.empty(x.shape), np.empty(x.shape)

if window is None:
    window = 'boxcar'

if nfft is None:
<bunch of nfft tests>

return welch(x, fs, window, nperseg, 0, nfft, detrend, return_onesided, scaling, axis)
```

This function is just a wrapper for `welch`.  And `welch` calls `csd`, which in turn uses `_spectral_helper`.  etc.  The error says it can't do anything with `welch`.

Study `scipy/signal/spectral.py` before trying to use `numba` to speed up any of its calculations.

Comment: Thank you.  I did, and saw that chain of calls. That's when I thought that I would have to optimize the whole spectral.py, thus my question if it is not already optimized.  I made some tests, and I suspect that it is already optimized.  I am going to focus on running periodogram in parallel, with no further optimization.

Comment: The two things I would look for are: loops that numba can convert to compiled code, or calls to code that is already compiled (most likely in `.so` file).  Sometimes it links to an external library (`fttpack`, `BLAS`) or there's a `pyx` source file (`cython`).

Comment: `_spectral_helper` ends up calling some function from `fftpack`.  That's a separate module.  The py code just takes care of loading compiled `fftpack` code.